# UI router keeps redirecting to index and doesnt load the states/views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to make states and load views with UI router, except it keeps redirecting me to index. I am not able to figure out what is happening.

I have declared the `app.js` somewhere else, I am just posting the `router.js` here.

**Code**

```
angular.module("MyApp").config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('clinicdashboard', {
      url: '/clinicdashboards',
      templateUrl: 'clinicdashboard/views/index.html',
      controller: 'clinicDashboardCtrl',
      resolve: {
        loginRequired: loginRequired,

        patientlist: ['$http', function($http) {
          console.log("hello");
          return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'users/api/getPatientList'
          });
        }]
      }
    })
    .state('patientList', {
      url: '/patientlist/:id',
      templateUrl: 'clinicdashboard/views/detail.html',
      controller: 'clinicDashboardCtrlDetail',
      resolve: {
        loginRequired: loginRequired
      }
    })
    .state('clinicProfile', {
      url: '/clinicProfile',
      templateUrl: 'clinicdashboard/views/clinicProfile.html',
      // controller:  'clinicDashboardCtrlDetail',
      resolve: {
        loginRequired: loginRequired
      }
    })
    .state('clinicProfile.clinicProfileEdit', {
      url: '/clinicProfileEdit',
      templateUrl: 'clinicdashboard/views/clinicProfileEdit.html',
      // controller:  'clinicDashboardCtrlDetail',
      resolve: {
        loginRequired: loginRequired
      }
    })
    function loginRequired($q, $location, $auth) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        deferred.resolve();
      } else {
        $location.path('/login');
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

I have put all the files in their correct directory.
It is showing no error on the console or nodemon or anywhere.

Its simply just redirecting me to `localhost`, even if I try to go to something like `localhost/clinicProfile`

Comment: Do you have /login route configured in $stateProvider?  Non-existing route may be causing this.

Comment: Yes, I have that configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try in your config,

```
  yourapp.config(
        function( $stateProvider,
                $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
})
```

By default it is false, so you can remove this settings if you have specified and try.
I just suspected this because in your url (localhost/clinicProfile) , there is no "#". Have you tried localhost/#/clinicProfile as well?

Also,  please try enabling HTML5Mode and and include this line in the head of index.html:  OR try $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false }); So $locationProvider wont be dependent on base tag.

Comment: @Pankaj, yes true, but Sarthak is not using '#' in his urls, So I suspect, he may be using html5Mode enabled.

Comment: correct. that might be case.. but in question OP has no `html5Mode` enable code in its config.

Comment: Yes, I am using HTML5Mode.. Infact, for the sake of argument, it disabled it, put the # in the url and then tried routing and it did. I have no clue why thats happening. I mean, shouldnt it be routing with HTML5Mode on too? @PankajParkar

Comment: @Sarthak, thanks for checking it quickly, can you try enabling HTML5Mode and and include this line in the head of index.html:

<base href="/"> OR try $locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
}); So $locationProvider wont be dependent on base tag

Comment: That worked like a charm @Ganesh .. If you could explain me what it did too? I am an amateur and I am working towards increasing my knowledge

Comment: By default, when you enable html5Mode, requireBase is true which means, you have to specify <base> tag in html head. If base tag is not needed, we can set requireBase:false so that $locationProvider won't look for base tag. Base tag is defined when you have your application in some sub-directory instead of root. Good that this helped Please mark as answer ( I have edited to include the solution) :)

Comment: Done.. Thank you for the explanation too. Cheers! @Ganesh